# How to set default date of jQuery datepicker with value already selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two date pickers in a startDate - endDate setup, and need the calendar of the endDate picker to open at the month of the selected startDate.

I have tried setting the default date as below (the date that the calendar opens with))

```
$("#endDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: $("#StartDate").datepicker("getDate"))
        });
```

but from what I have read and tried, it seems it can only be set if the datepicker in question does not have a selected date already, which is always the case on my page, and I guess would often be the case for datepickers generally, so am I missing something obvious?

At the moment I am setting the endDate to the startDate value when it is set, and it works as you might expect, but is not quite right. I don't want to update the endDate, I just want the calendar to open on the start date's month.

This fiddle might help illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/j7cNk/

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `showCurrentAtPos` option to show a certain month

```
var m1 = $("#StartDate").datepicker("getDate").getMonth();
    m2 = $("#endDate").datepicker("getDate").getMonth();

$('#endDate').datepicker('option', 'showCurrentAtPos', m2-m1 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Adeneo that is what I am doing at the moment, and it works as you might expect, but is not quite right. I don't want to update the endDate, I just want the calendar to open on the start date's month...

Comment: @GP24 - Okay, changed the answer to set the date for today and the month to the same as the other datepicker. You can just pass a  date object set to anything to getDate.

Comment: I'm hoping there is a way for the endDate calendar widget to open at the month of the startDate. I want to avoid changing the endDate at all so that if the user has already chosen a range and wants to set a second with a different startDate, they do not need to select the endDate again. if you see what I mean?

Comment: @GP24 - you could use the showCurrentAtPos option for that -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/r64Dy/

Comment: I'm not so sure, but if you change those two divs to inputs, you will have a very good approximation of the scenario...

Comment: With an input there doesn't seem to be a way to show another month without setting the date, so you have to change it. Maybe there's a way with an alt field and some trickery, but not sure how that would work either ?